# What is Ruby module.included?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to better my understanding of meta-programming in Ruby and am confused as to what `Module.included` is? My current understanding is that this is a callback invoked by Ruby whenever the module is included into another module or class. Other than that, what types of (meta-)programming constructs are these used in? Any examples?

Comment: When asking an extremely broad, open-ended question like "what is x?" it helps to state what your understanding is to give a starting point.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question to reflect my current understanding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Module#included` allows modules to inject both class and instance methods, and execute associated code, from a single include.

The [documentation for ActiveSupport::Concern](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) illustrates a typical use. It's injecting class methods into the calling class, and executing code. In this case, adding a [scope](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope).

```
module M
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end
end
```

And here's the ActiveSupport::Concern version which does the same thing, but adds declarative syntax sugar.

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module M
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }
  end

  class_methods do
    ...
  end
end
```

With `included` a class simply includes the module. It allows the module to be one neat package: instance methods, class methods, and setup code.

```
class Thing
  # Class and instance methods are injected, and the new scope is added.
  include M
end
```

Without `included` a module can only inject instance methods. Class methods would have to be added separately, as well as executing any setup code.

```
module M
  def some_instance_method
    ...
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def setup
      scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Thing
  # Inject the instance methods
  include M

  # Inject the class methods
  extend M::ClassMethods

  # Run any setup code.
  setup
end
```

---

Other examples might be registering a class, for example as an available plugin.

```
module Plugin
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      register_as_plugin(base)
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def register_as_plugin(klass)
      ...
    end
  end
end

class Thing
  include Plugin
end
```

Or adding necessary accessors.

```
module HasLogger
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      attr_writer :logger
    end
  end

  def logger
    @logger ||= Rails.logger
  end
end

class Thing
  include HasLogger
end
```

Comment: why we need ```base.``` and ```base.class_eval``` ?

Comment: @TPR Because `included` is called on the module, the class which included it is passed in as `base`. In the `HasLogger` example, inside `self.included` `self` is `HasLogger` and `base` is `Thing`. If it did `attr_writer :logger` without the `base.class_eval` it would add the attribute to `HasLogger`. We want to add the attribute to `Thing`. `base.class_eval` lets us do that; inside `base.class_eval` `self` is `Thing`. We could also have written `base.attr_writter :logger`.